# Table goes right side instead of staying centered

Tags: tables, floats

I just started using LateX, this table stays on the right no matter what. How can I center it by using the left space?
[image: Code]
[image: Result]

Comment: It looks as if your table is too wide for the linewidth. I thik I'd switch rows and columns

Comment: Welcome to Tex.SE! Posting pictures of code is not a good idea as it means all the effort in finding solutions is left to the people here, could you copy and paste a small example that can compile please, starting with your `\documentclass{}` and ending with `\end{document}`, you can use the `lipsum` package to generate filler text

Comment: Please never post images of code, no-one wants to re-type your example in order to test it. As Patricio already mentioned, your table is wider than the text width and thus of course will not be centered in relation to it.

Comment: Unrelated but it is better to just write `$63 \pm 1$` instead of `63 $\pm$ 1` the whole thing is a mathematical object to be typeset, not just `\pm`. Additionally, you should have a look at the `siunitx` package to format units and table data.

Comment: Thank you all! Next time I'll write the code in the question, sorry :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx,booktabs}
\sisetup{uncertainty-mode=separate}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}
        \centering
        \begin{tabular}{cSS}
            \toprule
            {$N$} & {diametro (\unit{\mm})} & {$\cos\theta$ ($\qty[print-unity-mantissa = false]{e-6}{\radian}$)} \\\midrule
            7 & 48\pm1 & 99990\pm1\\
            6 & 63\pm1&99983\pm1\\
            5&74\pm1&99977\pm1\\
            4&88\pm1&99967\pm1\\
            3&95\pm1&99962\pm1\\
            2&103\pm1&99955\pm1\\
            1&109\pm1&99949\pm1\\\bottomrule
        \end{tabular}
        \caption{Caption}
        \label{tab:my_label}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image: Result]

Answer (score 0):

Without interchanges of columns and rows:

[image]

By use of `tabularray` table and enabled two line text in the first column:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{siunitx}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}
    \small
    \sisetup{uncertainty-mode = separate,
             tight-spacing}
\begin{tblr}{hline{1,2,Z},
             colspec = {@{} Q[c,m] *{7}{X[c, si={table-format=5.0(1)}]} @{}},
             colsep  = 3pt,
             row{1}  = {guard}
             }
$N$ & 7         &   6       &   5       &   4       &   3       &   2       &   1       \\ 
{diametro\\ (\unit{\mm})}
    & 48(1)     & 63(1)     & 74(1)     & 88(1)     & 95(1)     &103(1)     & 109(1)    \\
{$\cos\theta$\\ (\qty{e-6}{\radian})}
    & 99990(1)  & 99983(1)  & 99977(1)  & 99967(1)  & 99962(1)  & 99955(1)  & 99949(1)  \\
    \end{tblr}
\caption{Caption}
\label{tab:my_label}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```